# max() function on list with an integrer

Tags: python

I have a list composed of integers, and I would like to do this :

```
 freeSushi = max(sushiPrices <= sushiPrice)
```

`sushiPrice` being an integer and `sushiPrices` being a list.

Any idea of how I can do this ?

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? You want to find the maximum price under a certain limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use filter before applying max

```
max(filter(lambda price: price <= sushiPrice, sushiPrices)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work, if "something" was a list of prices less than or equal to sushiPrice:

```
freeSushi = max(something)
```

So how can we create a list of prices less than sushiPrice?  Comprehend?

Answer (score -1):

Use a for loop like so:

```python
for i in sushiPrices:
    if i > sushiPrice:
        del sushiPrices[sushiPrices.index(i)]
freeSushi = max(sushiPrices)
```